# ZipException: duplicate entry: junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class when running tests in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to run some tests into Firebase test lab platform and I'm finding a problem:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class

The tests works fine when I run them locally in a virtual device.

I'm working all day in this and I can't find a valid solution for me :(

Here's my dependencies:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
// Dagger
// apt command comes from the android-apt plugin
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.7.0'
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:1.2'
compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.7.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.4'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2')  {
    exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'design'
}
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by determining which libraries are using a class with that name. 
 Android Studio you can use `open file` and type ActiveTestSuite.  This will autocomplete with all the matching classes.  For example, when I do this it seems to come from a junit class.

I'm not sure why you would only see this on Firebase.  Possibly see if there's a flag to ensure the test build runs a *clean* operation before running.